# Save Outlook credentials in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, windows-10, roaming-profile, credentials

I have an AD with roaming user profiles. Credentials, for example for Office365, don't seem to be stored in the roaming profile, however. When the user switches to a new computer for the first time, he will have to enter all of his credentials again (such as for Outlook, for Sticky Notes, and others). Understandably, this doesn't meet the users' expectation.

I tried finding an answer for this myself and it seems that this could be solved using something called "Roaming Credentials". Unfortunately, most of the search results are either very old or they are simply not that clear, most of the times they speak about user certificates instead of other types of credentials.

Hopefully someone here can help me out.

- What does Roaming Credentials actually do?
- How is it related to Roaming Profiles?
- Do I need Roaming Profiles to use Roaming Credentials?
- Very specifically, I'd like for my users to log in with Outlook once to Office365 and have their credentials saved even when they change computers. Is this possible with Roaming Credentials and if no, how would I go about this?